# AngularJS - check for null item in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using ng-repeat to display rows in a table and when two items are not null I want to display true in HTML. I've searched but I can't find an expression or ng directive.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Account Enabled?</th>
                        <th>Username</th>
                        <th>Date Registered</th>
                        <th>User Displayname</th>
                        <th>Password Reset?</th>
                        <th>Password Valid To</th>
                        <th>Log On Count</th>
                        <th>Last Logged On</th>
                        <th>Is Primary Account?</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="item in onlineAccounts.CommunicationMethods">
                        <td>
                            {{item.IsEnabled}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{item.UserName}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{item.CreatedOn}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{item.OnlineDisplayName}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div ng-if="item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo != null &&  item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo != null">True</div>
                            <div ng-if="item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo == null item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo == null">False</div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{item.LogOnCount}}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{item.LastLoggedOn}}
                        </td>
                    <td>
                            {{item.IsDefault}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

This is the line I want to change:

```
  <div ng-if="item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo != null &&  item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo != null">True</div>
                            <div ng-if="item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo == null item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo == null">False</div>
```

I get the error:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'item' is an unexpected token at column 40 of the expression [item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo == null item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo == null] starting at [item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo == null].
```

Is there any angular guru that can help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot `&&`

```
<div ng-if="item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo == null && item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo == null">False</div>
---------------------------------------------------^^
```

Comment: thanks that worked. I'll mark it as correct when SO let's me.

Comment: Bingo +1 for timings :-p

Answer (score 1):

You forgot &&

```
<div ng-if="item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo == null && item.PasswordResetTokenValidTo == null">False</div>
```

Comment: @R3tep when i was giving the answer i couldn't see your answer.It's not duplicate it's just a lag b/w timings answers. An i appreciaite that you won  by 33 seconds :-P

Comment: This is not a race ;)

Comment: That's what i was saying man this is not race i was writing the answe and your answer till then not placed on the board :-P